# What is the order of the present Varah Kalpa in Brahma's life?

Tags: brahma, yuga, skanda-purana, kalpa, manvantara

The Skanda Purana says that Sati was born in the **1st Manvantar of the Pitri Kalpa** which was the 30th Kalpa in the second Parardha of Brahma.

[image]

The text again says that Parvati was born in the Vaivasvat i.e. 7th Manvantar of the present **Varah Kalpa**.

[image]

Does this imply that the **present Varah Kalpa is the 31st one** or were there other Kalpas too in between? If there were what is the order of our present Kalpa in Brahma's second Parardha?**

EDIT: **Vayu Purana Chapter 21** mentions 34 Kalpas:

> The kalpas since the
> original creation were as follows. (1) Bhava. (2) Bhuva. (3) Tapah. (4) Bhava. (5) Rambha. (6)
> Ritu. (7) Kratu. (8) Vahni. (9) Havyavahana. (10) Savitra. (11) Bhuvah. (12) Oushika. (13)
> Kushika. (14) Gandharva. (15) Rishabha. (16) Shadaja. (17) Marjaliya. (18) Madhyama. (19)
> Vairaja. The great Vairaja Manu was born in this kalpa and his son was the great sage
> Dadhichi. (20) Nishada. The race of nishadas (hunters) were created during this period. (21)
> Panchama. (22) Meghavahana. The word megha means cloud and vahana means to bear. In
> this kalpa, Vishnu adopted the form of a cloud and bore Shiva on his back. It is thus that the kalpa received its name. (23) Chintaka. (24) Akuti. (25) Vijnati. (26) Mana. (27) Bhava. (28)
> Vrihat. (29) Shvetalohita. (30) Rakta. (31) Pitavasa. (32) Sita. (33) Krishna (34) Vishvarupa.

**So then are we in the 35th Kalpa?**

Comment: Do you have the Vayu Purana book?

Comment: Different Puranas mention different number for same Sweta Varaha kalpa.

Comment: @TheDestroyer there must be some efforts at a consensus on this? Or has no one ever tried to come to a conclusion. BTW are the Shwet Varah and Varah Kalpa the same?

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal yes. Sweta Varaha Kalpa and Varaha Kalpa are same as at beginning of this Kalpa, Lord Vishnu took Sweta Varaha (white Boar) incarnation. But there is other Kalpa called Sweta kalpa which is different. All Stories of Shiva Purana happened in Sweta kalpa while Vishnu Purana stories are of current Kalpa (Sweta varaha).

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal It's actually confusing. I tried to find out chronological order of Kalpas from all Puranas. But due to varied nature of orders, i couldn't come to any conclusion.

Comment: @TheDestroyer thanks for clarifying about the Varah Kalpa. I am wondering does any other Puran mention what the current Kalpa is? The Skanda Puran indirectly says it is the 31st but the Vayu doesnt really mention it right. The other Kalpas beyond 31 may be those of the future?

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal I have read that other Purana mentioning different chronological order of Kalpas. It's actually difficult to find the order and a complex job with limited info we have. But what's intersting is, Sridhara Swami (oldest commentator of Srimad Bhagavatam) says Padma kalpa is same as Sweta Varaha kalpa, as mentioned by Prabhupada [here](https://prabhupadabooks.com/sb/2/10/47). I would like to see how he concluded it.

Comment: About the Meghavahana kalpa.  Someone has said here //Meghavahana. The word megha means cloud and vahana means to bear. In this kalpa, Vishnu adopted the form of a cloud and bore Shiva on his back. It is thus that the kalpa received its name. // In the Lingapurana Uttara bhaga, 8th chapter is the information in verses 9 to 12 that Vishnu, in the form of a cloud, propitiated Shiva and obtained very great boons. https://sa.wikisource.org/s/4jt     This is just for information in this discussion.