# How many kalpas ago was Sati born?

Tags: parvati, sati-goddess

I heard Parvati was born in *Varaha Kalpa*. And Also read the current kalpa's name is *bhadrakalpa* as shown on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalpa_(aeon)).

There are following things I want to know:

- Difference between Kalpa of Sati(also name) and current(bhadrakalpa) kalpa.
- Time difference between Sati's death and Parvati's birth (just
  overview, not in brief) even in eprox.
- Difference between Parvati's birth Kapla and current Kalpa.

It would be **best** if I got list of Kalpas from Sati's Kalpa to Present Kalpa(if possible). In [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalpa_(aeon)) of wiki list given according to Matasya purana but from that list I couldn't grab the information about difference between Sati's and current Kalpa.

Comment: Current Kalpa name is Shveta Varaha Kalpa as far as I know.

Comment: @Sinister Thanks for the info, I just read on wiki in my mentioned link. I am **not** sure if wiki told current info about kalpas. You can show your views as answer since I want to know correct info about Sati's to current kalpa :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per [**Chapter 19**](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/27477/62f_chapter_19_1.pdf), **Prabhasa Khanda of Skanda Purana**, Parvati Devi was born to Himavan at end of Chakshusha  Manvantara (6th Manvantara) and beginning of Vaivasvara Manvantara in Varaha Kalpa.

As per this chapter, Varaha Kalpa is 31st Kalpa in 51st year of Brahma. 30th kalpa was Pitri Kalpa and Sati was born in Swayambhuva Manvantara (1st Manvantara) of Pitri Kalpa. Rudra lived without Shakti for period of 21 Manvantaras (14 in Pitri Kalpa and 7 in Varaha kalpa).

> Lord Shiva says
>
> 54-56. In the second Parårdha Of Brahma, the thirtieth Kalpa was
> well-known as Pitr kalpa, In the beginning of the Svåyambhuva
> Manvantara therein, you were (known as) Sati. O great goddess, the
> Daksa who was then your father was born  of prana, the patriarch. But
> in this Manvantara, O goddess,  Daksha was born Of Pracetas.
>
> 57. Now, O my beloved, Daksa Will be born Of the right  (thumb). All the Brähmanas beginning With Daksa  are born in every Yuga.
> 58. Thus bereaved of you formerly, O my beloved, I was  separated from you till the Chakshusha  Manvantara Of the Varähakalpa.
> 59. This is the twenty-first Manu (i.e. beginning from  Sväyambhuva Of Pitrkalpa and ending with of Väräha Kalpa) in the Kalpa called Väråha.
>     O great goddess, in every Kalpa you will have a different name.
> 60. In this Väräha Kalpa, O goddess, you became Pärvati  obtained by Himavän through his penance, when the Cäksusa  Manvantara has passed
>     off.
> 61. O beautiful lady, due to the anger of Daksha you had  to be separated from me for the duration Of a day Of Brahma.  Your span of
>     life is the period of his six months.

Comment: Great answer, But what about current kalpa? 30th kalpa was Sati's kalpa and 31st kalpa was of Parvati. What's the no. of current kalpa? And also how many manvatars are use to be in one kalpa?

Comment: @Rishabh Varaha kalpa is same as Sweta Varaha kalpa which is current Kalpa. Also, many Puranas say we are in 51st year of Brahma. So, most probably it is current Kalpa. But other Puranas give different number for Varaha Kalpa. See [What is the order of the present Varah Kalpa n Brahma's life?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20689/3500)