# Are there any more details about previous Kalpas in scriptures?

Tags: brahma, kalpa

Reading about Kalpa on this site, my understanding is:

1. Current Brahma completed 50 years
2. Currently Brahma is in 51st year and on first day of the 51st year
3. Each of Brahma's day includes one Kalpa (day) and one Night (Pralaya)
4. Brahma's year consists of 360 Brahma days
5. So, Brahma has completed 50 years times 360 days times one Kalpas/Pralaya for each day.
6. Which means, 18,000 Kalpas and same number Pralayas already completed in current Brahma's time

First question: is my understandings correct?

This [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21446/is-each-of-the-18-mahapurans-related-to-a-different-kalpa?r=SearchResults) mentions about multiple Kalpas. When 18 thousand Kalpas completed, the list in this answer are the recent Kalpas? Are there any more details about previous Kalpas in scriptures?

Comment: Your assumptions 1-6 are correct

Comment: You can check out <https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21467/20129> For a small reference to Pitri Kalpa in which Sati was born